# How to catch strange undefined behaviour in C++ code?

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, gdb, boost-asio

I have strange behaviour in server program. In simple example it works fine (I insert traces everywhere, in pion and asio).

```
#include <pion/http/server.hpp>
#include <pion/http/response_writer.hpp>
#include <pion/http/response_reader.hpp>
#include <pion/http/request_writer.hpp>
#include <pion/logger.hpp>
#include <pion/scheduler.hpp>

int main()
{
   pion::single_service_scheduler shed;
   shed.set_num_threads(1);
   boost::shared_ptr<pion::http::server> server
   (new pion::http::server(shed, 5000));
   server->add_resource("/", handlerFunction);
   server->start();
   sleep(5);
}
```

output is like this. Construct socket for acceptor, construct socket for client, tcp connection is created, all works fine.

```
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
Address of socket is: 0x9855fa4 value: -1
after service construct
1422519945 INFO pion.http.server Added request handler for HTTP resource: 
1422519945 INFO pion.http.server Starting server on port 5000
before connection create
before connection constructor called
basic io object constructor
basic_stream_socket::construct
Address of socket is: 0x9857514 value: -1
after impl.construct
after service construct
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
after service construct
ssl socket constructed
connection constructor, is_ssl: 0
after connection create: 0x98574f8
before accept
after accept
```

In more complicated program with same code, but with oracle and many other libraries output is like this.

```
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
Address of socket is: 0xbfe47a64 value: -1
after service construct
1422525476 INFO pion.http.server Added request handler for HTTP resource: 
before connection create
basic io object constructor
after service construct
basic io object constructor
after service construct
after connection create: 0x8fe8b88
before accept
in connection::async_accept
after accept
```

No second socket created, actually, there is no call of `connection::create`, but connection has address as you can see. I have idea, that somewhere something writes on address of function `connection::create` (or something like). Can you please help, how can I catch this?

Comment: Assuming `clang` or `gcc` they have sanitizers, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22699881/1708801) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20738232/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour thanks, but there is no gcc 4.9 for ubuntu yet (in stable repo, also this will take a while for rebuild all libs for gcc 4.9), clang sanitizer should be used with -stdlib=libc++ as I can see, but pion use internally tr1/unordered_map.

Comment: Was just problems with build, some libraries with C++11, some without... Without C++11 all works fine...

Comment: Oh interesting, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28201173/1708801) is related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ubuntu, I like to run with `valgrind` (http://valgrind.org/).

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
valgrind ./mypgrogram
```

It doesn't report all issues, but when it does, it will report the nature and origin.

Also recommended:

```
valgrind --db-attach=yes ./myprogram
```

Which allows you to debug (backtrace, inspect) and continue the program when a violation/uninitialized memory reference is detected.

> On some older Ubunti I had to use `sudo` to make `valgrind` be able to attach `gdb`:
>
> ```
> sudo -E valgrind --db-attach=yes ./myprogram
> ```

If `tr1/unordered_map` should be quite trivial to replace with `std::unordered_map`

E.g. with a quick hack

```
#include <unordered_map>

namespace std { namespace tr1 {

    using std::unordered_map;
    using std::hash;
    // etc...
} }
```

Of course this is not good practice, and you might just want to typedef between `std::unordered_map` and `std::tr1::unordered_map` instead, but in the interest of quick checks...

Comment: Thanks, tried with valgrind, but there is many-many memory errors from oracle and nothing else. Will try with --db-attach...

Comment: There might be suppression rules for the oracle libraries you mention. Also, you might be able to cut oracle out of the loop (divide-and-conquer).

Comment: Actually, now I can't reproduce this situation on my machine, remove all traces, etc, but no... Probably moon phase has been replaced...

Comment: Or a full rebuild occurred :)

Comment: reproduced... But valgrind, either with db-attach says only about uninitialized variable in implementation, no idea about `connection::create`... It just not called.

Comment: @ForEveR Only one way, IMHO: keep reducing (either by eliminating more and more, or by starting with a fresh project and adding things until it breaks). Pay special attention to shared library compatibilities etc.

Comment: Hard way, but may be I will try to do this. Thanks.