# Official status of c++11 support in gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

This is **not** a question about which c++11 features are supported by gcc (I believe since 4.8 the c++11 support is pretty complete), but if there are any known problems in using them in production code.

The reason I'm asking is that I had a look at the [manual for gcc5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc.pdf) and in the section "Language Standards Supported by GCC" it reads:

> [...] most of which have been implemented in an **experimental** C++11 mode in GCC.

That word *experimental* got me a little worried, but on the other hand, c++14 isn't even mentioned, although I believe GCC supports all of those features, too. 
So is this just an oversight in the documentation or are there really any valid concerns against using c++11 features in production code that will be compiled with gcc5.2 (4.8)?

Comment: Related: [When will Gnu C++ support C++11 without explicitly asking for it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21221411/86967).

Comment: I run across the same isue. I though that c++11 was fully supported in gcc (specially in 2016!)  .. but it's still tagged as experimental ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like actually it's `experimental` only on words. In [gcc 6.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) it will not be `experimental` more.

> The default mode for C++ is now -std=gnu++14 instead of -std=gnu++98.

But now, default mode is `gnu++98` and so, it's `experimental` (one of the reasons, why we don't use C++11/C++14 now).

Comment: Wait, really?  You don't use C++11 because the compiler forces you to pass `-std` flags to it?  /pity.

Comment: @Yakk one of the reasons, but not because `-std` flag. Because `expiremental` word. And yeah, I don't like it.) But boost helps.

Comment: Any infos on when gcc 6.0 is supposed to be released?

Comment: Regarding the default mode, I didn't actually expect them to change it as the didn't even change to c++03 in the past.

Comment: @MikeMB no information. But: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-10/msg00113.html and so on about dev steps: https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html

Comment: @MikeMB C++03 was subsumed into C++98 mode (they are identical under both clang and gcc: C++03 is considered bug fixes on C++98, which I figured out researching [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48924/23424))

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ForEveR: Have you encountered any actual problems in c++11/14 mode or is it just company policy to not use anything labeled *experimental*?

Comment: @MikeMB was one problem with libraries builded with C++03 and core project builded with C++11. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211746/how-to-catch-strange-undefined-behaviour-in-c-code , after that C++11 was disabled due `expiremental` word.

Comment: Well, I understand your case. Relying on a support that's tagged as "experimental" explicitly in the user manual of gcc is not sane for production environments.