# if xcode can support two kind c++Dialect at the same time?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, sdk, dialect

In my project, I use the first sdk, it needs me to 
set :

```
    "c++ Language Dialect" to "C+=98[-std=c++98]",
    "c++ Standard Library" to "libstdc++(GUN C++ standard library)";
however ,the project also needs the second sdk,it needs to set 
and the second sdk,it needs me to set the 
    "c++ Language Dialect" to "C++11[-std=c++11]",
    "c++ Standard Library" to "libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++ support)";
```

(I just need to use the first SDK at some particular situation )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637699/c03-library-with-c11-source-code?answertab=active#tab-top  it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the build flags per (sub-)project.

To do so: Simply select the first SDK project in the navigation bar and set the flags appropriately in the column called as your project with the blue project icon. (It should be the third column counted from the left, the first is named *Resolved*, the second is named as your target, which is has the same name as your project, but has a brown icon.)

Do the same with the second project (and different flags of course …)

Comment: i add the first sdk as a static project import into my project,and set is using c+=98 dialect,however,when i build it ,it shows many errors ,such as "...std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:s_122::init(char const*, bool) in libsubShare.a(UD5059.o)..."

Comment: it seems a c++ error,my first sdk using "... c+= dialect ... " can compiler alone;however when it imported it compilers error.....

Comment: "can compile alone" does mean "using command line" or "using Xcode with a single project"?